# Check if browser supports MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, html

How does one write an if clause that would check to see if `MutationObserver` is supported?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator

> The **in operator** returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> prop in objectName
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **prop**
>
> A string or symbol representing a property name or array index
>   (non-symbols will be coerced to strings).
>
> **objectName**
>
> Name of an object.

```
if ("MutationObserver" in window) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: @KarlMorrison Alternatively `if (window["MutationObserver"]) {// do stuff}`

Comment: it's better with dotted notation: `if (window.MutationObserver) { .. }`

Comment: @FezVrasta _"it's better with dotted notation"_ Why would dot notation be "better" ?

Comment: @FezVrasta  Note "better" does not appear defined at linked page ? _"However, by using dot notation where possible, you can save three characters every time."_ Is saving three characters reason for "better" ?

Comment: It's the title of the page "is better written in dot notation"... And it's not just saving few characters, it's easier to understand (you know you are using an object and not an array at a glance) and is the common way to write it (used by all the js scripts of the world)